# TP-Link Router Internet Source

Tags: router

I have a TL-WR941ND Wireless Router. The WAN port is **NOT** plugged with any cable. However, the router is internally configured to the ISP username and password as if the WAN port is plugged with a DSL cable. One of the LAN ports is attached by cable to a TL-SF1008D switch.

Router is providing internet perfectly. Is that normal? Please can someone explain this to me!

Comment: Is your internet connection plugged into that switch?  If so, the ISP device may be acting as your router.

Answer (score 0):

You're using your router as a bridge and access point. It is not doing any routing -- some other device connected to the switch probably is.

If the router is not connected to the WAN, then the WAN port shouldn't be connected to anything.